# Track Entity Framework Progress

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using entity framework to insert a large amount of data.
I would like to get a Progress for the inserts (display it to the user).

Is there anything within EF to achive this?

Comment: while you cant AFAIK do any montioring after you actually send the query to SQL there a bunch of performance tweeks you can do before then to make EF fast enough it probably doesnt need monitoring. I wrote a bunch of articles on EF performance earlier in the year. the one thats most relevant is http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/05/entityframework-performance-and.html, with these tweeks i get about 1000 rows/sec for inserts on my machine

Comment: I had similar problem. I decided to use SqlBulkCopy instead of EF and it was so fast that I don´t need to monitor progress anymore - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Comment: @Luke I need to insert around 150k rows, so just tuning won't help for me ;)

Comment: @OndraMorský Bulk copy is not an option, since I have to copy quite complex structured data - while I do not want to analyze it.

Comment: @Jaster i think your best bet would be to write in batches then and use them for progress. Batches make a lot of sense anyway to keep the tracked entity collection managable

Comment: There are multiple limitations for my case, that make batches not usefull at all, so I will stick to EF. My question is not if there is a different way (than EF) to track progress. I am looking for solution to do so in EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long answer short: It is not possible.